# nRF52840 debug SWD Raspberry Pi 3B+ flash_writing error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, openocd, nrf52, swd

I have problem witch writing flash to nRF52840 dongle by Raspberry PI 3B+. I tried to change the bootloader and when I was cleaning the memory with the "nrf5 mass_erase" command, raspberry said that nothing cleared, and since it didn't clear, I thought I could unplug it. I know you shouldn't pull it out if you clear the flash memory but I didn't know I did it.

Now when I connect it to the computer it does not detect me at all. I have 1.8V between the VDD and GND pins, which means that the memory is cleared by default. Due to the fact that I cut off the device with the SB2 cutter and connected the SB1, ensuring external 3.3V voltage for VDD and GND. I tried to upload the software but I have the following errors. I looked at the internet and the problems were similar but in my case I didn't want to help.

I wanted to do what is in the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5wub5ywzTU&list=PLKGiH5V9SS1g90s9mHTMPJT1i8N4fXWNT&index=2

Openocd.cfg

```
# Raspi1 peripheral_base address
# bcm2835gpio_peripheral_base 0x20000000
# Raspi2 and Raspi3 peripheral_base address
#bcm2835gpio_peripheral_base 0x3F000000

# Raspi1 BCM2835: (700Mhz)
# bcm2835gpio_speed_coeffs 113714 28
# Raspi2 BCM2836 (900Mhz):
# bcm2835gpio_speed_coeffs 146203 36
# Raspi3 BCM2837 (1200Mhz): 
# bcm2835gpio_speed_coeffs 194938 48

# pi interfece
interface bcm2835gpio
bcm2835gpio_peripheral_base 0x3F000000
bcm2835gpio_speed_coeffs 194938 48
bcm2835gpio_swd_nums 25 24

# transport
transport select swd

# target
set CHIPNAME nrf52840
source [find target/nrf52.cfg]

# Uncomment & lower speed to address errors
 adapter_khz 800

init
targets
reset halt
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find i must set REGOUT0 but i dont't know how